Can i use my brother's SSN and bank account for brokerage account to do intraday trading in USA with his permission, any legal issues
My brother is an F1 student and I'm a US green card holder. He wants to engage in intraday trading in the US stock market using my personal information (SSN, name, bank account). I would transfer the profits to him. Are there any legal, tax, or regulatory implications to this arrangement

Are there any legal, tax, or regulatory implications to this arrangement - yes, there are.

He will also almost surely blow your account. Most retail traders lose money. Therefore, I would also worry about how you deal with this situation.

Is there a specific reason he needs to have a (fake) US identity to do so? Are there no brokerages available in his country of origin he can use?

Why does your brother dislike you so much?

I am not an immigration attorney.  But if brokerages won't let an F1 student do intraday trading, my wager is that this is not activity that is compatible with that visa type since F1 visas are for full-time students.  So your brother would likely be jeopardizing his visa in addition to your finances.  https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/54996/investment-options-for-f1-visa-students-in-usa

@JustinCave: foreign-student visas don't restrict investing, although they do restrict employment much as your linked Q says (there is an exception for limited-term employment in the degree field arranged by the school called OPT = Optional Practical Training). A brokerage might still decline them because (1) mandated KYC is harder (thus more expensive) (2) tax reporting is different (possibly more expensive) (3) all students foreign and domestic generally don't have much (or even any) money -- especially after day-trading

@dave_thompson_085 - Still not an immigration attorney.  But according to the answer I linked to, day trading can be considered employment activity.  As would investing for others.  Both of which would seemingly describe this proposal.


Are there any legal, tax, or regulatory implications to this arrangement

Yes. Lots of of them.
These are two completely different events here. If you trade with your SSN and your account, you are fully responsible for all profits, losses, and taxes associated with it regardless if trade on behalf of your brother or not. You are buying and selling, not him.
You can have a separate agreement with your brother on how to direct with investments to buy and what to do with the profit and losses (after taxes & fees).
Overall this is a terrible idea. You are fully responsible for all taxes and losses associated wit the trading and you may also owe gift tax when you send  money abroad. Its possible that your brother will make decision that will costs you 1000s of dollars which won't help the family peace.
